# How do I interpolate and create better Contour maps using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, data-visualization

I am trying to generate contour maps using irregular data after gridding the data in python. I am getting something like the image on left while I am trying to get a contour plot like the one on the right side without any white spaces in my plot (unplotted space ?)

[image: Contour 1] [image: Contour 2]

I am initially creating a grid using the below code

```
def grid(x, y, z, resX=100, resY=100):
  xi = linspace(min(x), max(x), resX)
  yi = linspace(min(y), max(y), resY)
  Z = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')
  X, Y = meshgrid(xi, yi)
  return X, Y, Z
X, Y, Z = grid(x, y, z)
contour = plt.contourf(X,Y,Z)
```

Where x,y,z are columns from my csv file.

I tried using other methods like using `matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf` but the plot looks similar to the one I am getting.

Rbf from `scipy.interpolate.rbf` gives a plot similar to the one on right side if I use a subset of my data but it doesn't work for large datasets.

Comment: Check `griddata` docs;  and the `Z` values.  I suspect the white spaces are `nan` values, for grid points outside the `hull` of the data.  That is, where it would have to extrapolate.

Comment: @hpaulj im dropping the missing values if you mean that. TIA

Comment: Have you played with any of the `contour` keyword values?

Comment: @hpaulj I tried increasing the contour levels. I worked with `plt.contourf` before switching to `plt.tricontourf` as this does not require me to explicitly grid the data. The results are similar for `contourf` and `tricontourf`

Comment: Sorry that don't really understand what you are looking for. Will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extrapolate in order to cover the empty spaces. Griddata interpolates within a convex hull of your data. In order to extrapolate the data you can use SciPy’s RBF (radial basis functions) interpolation. There are a few interpolation options with RBF (linear, cubic, Gaussian, ect.). Another option is to use sklearn’s “Gaussian process regression” to predict the values throughout your grid space. This option will require more work that SciPy’s built in RBF but it’s also more flexible.